# Is the lowercase "dockerfile" file name supported and how long has it been supported?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, naming-conventions

I noticed I could use "dockerfile" with a lowercase "d". I have a client that is quite upset that we submitted a solution using a lowercase "d" on "dockerfile" instead of the uppercase "Dockerfile".

Clearly, Docker allows the lowercase "d" as it is not giving me any error messages. So, my question is how long has support for the lowercase "d" existed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this was the change -

https://github.com/spf13/docker/commit/7b1a2bbf701dfc961d9e2e00cc2e56544bb162b4

This change was pushed on 17 Feb 2015. Probably we didn't realise it because it looks for a `Dockerfile` and falls back to `dockerfile`.

Comment: The commit is not accessible.

Comment: The link is dead, but a possible related PR around the same date was submitted here https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/10858 and the accompanying commit is here https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/10858/commits/15924f238503ffe44e5fcb99415ff753a36e5971